# Jquery: Refresh html element which was added through jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have added a row dynamically using jquery as a part of some ajax request something like:

```
                        var newRow = $("<tr class='rowItemValid'>");
                        newRow.attr('id', data.user.id);

                        var cols = "";
                        var dob = (data.user.date_of_birth).split('T')
                        cols += '<td>'+data.user.title+'</td>';
                        cols += '<td>'+data.user.first_name+'</td>';
                        cols += '<td>'+data.user.last_name+'</td>';
                        cols += '<td>'+data.user.email+'</td>';
                        cols += '<td>'+dob[0]+'</td>';
                        cols +=  '</ul></div></td>';
                        cols += '<td><a url="/home/"  class="target-click">Edit</a></td>';

                     newRow.append(cols);
                    $('.validTable').append(newRow);
```

jquery click event does not happening for that added row. If any other row is clicked and after that new row which was added using jquery is clicked then click event works for added row, but does not works first time.

I added row and pressed f5 then that added row works for click event , so that part needs to be reloaded or refreshed

how can i refresh that added row ?

**EDIT: click event**
$(document).ready(

```
function(){
    $(".target-click").click(

           function(){

               //click task
    }
 );
```

});

Comment: Because is missed closed tag for `<tr>` ... means `</tr>`

Comment: can you show click event?

Comment: Looks like you've missed the tag `</tr>`.

Comment: Use delegation because `tr` is a dynamically generated element. `$('.validtable').click(... if (e.target..hasClass('target-click').{..`

Comment: `$('.validtable').on('click', '.target-click', function(){});` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use delegation because your `tr` is a dynamically generated element.

Something like this:

```
$('.validtable').on('click', function(e) { 
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.hasClass('target-click')) { 

        // you check if the element clicked meets your criteria
        ...
        // your click handler code here
    }
});
```

Or, better still:

```
$('.validtable').on('click', '.target-click', function(e) { 

    // you specify criteria selector as the second argument
    ...
});
```

An example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ZH5kc/

Comment: Why not `.on(event, selector, handler)`?

Comment: for some reason if condition is not getting true. please check post for what target looks like.

Comment: @naveenyadav: Please check carefully if your code is generating malformed html. Have you fixed unmatched `tr`? I created a small fiddle so that you could see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ZH5kc/

Answer (score 0):

This is not because you need to refresh the reason is described below -

1. When the first time page was loaded, the jQuery document ready was called once and your table had say 4 rows, all the events were bind. So, it works when the page is loaded.
2. But when you add a dynamic row, the 5th row, the `document.ready` is not called again and thus all the binding codes that you used to bind events are not run again and so the new row has no event bind to it and thus it does not work. Then you load again, (1) happens and all works as expected.

To resolve do the followings (any) -

A. If loading is not a problem then load the page after each add. Say -

```
windows.location.href = window.location.href
```

B. Oh yeah of course, `event delegation`, may be I am a bit behind on that.. Thanks @Yury

```
$('.validtable').on('click', '.target-click', function(){
    ........
});
```

Comment: Two words: event delegation.